# Updating child row locks parent row in PostgreSQL (foreign key, 9.1)

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, locking, postgresql-9.1

I have a problem with transaction isolation, let's considering two transactions:

First transaction 1 does an update in a row on table 1, and then, transaction 2 does an update in a row from child table that references the pk from table 1 that was updated in transaction 1, analysing the transactions we can see a lock, transaction 2 will be locked until the transaction 1 be committed or rollebacked, is there a way to avoid this lock? My transaction 1 does not affect table 2, because it was an update in a specific column.
P.S. My PostgreSQL version is 9.1, I have checked PostgresSQL 9.6 and it does not happen, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution adopted was split the commonly updated columns into a separate table, it solves, because Postgres won't  block the parent table.

Answer (score 1):

You've already identified how to fix it: upgrade. PostgreSQL 9.6 has a feature, `FOR KEY SHARE` locks, that are used by foreign keys to avoid locking the whole row when a child row is being inserted/updated. This feature is not in 9.1.

Alternately, you can `DROP` the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint and rely on the application to maintain consistency. PostgreSQL will no longer take a `FOR SHARE` row lock on the parent row when the child row is inserted/updated, since there's no longer a formal foreign key relationship.

Comment: In this moment I can't upgrade my PostgreSQL, I have found a workaround, I wrote an answer in my post. Thank you.